# Bootstrap popover loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I am trying to show "Loading..." text or spinner image until the dynamic ajax content loads because I have a very large number of data to fetch with takes at least 2-3 seconds to fully load here is my Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({  
    trigger: "hover",
    title:fetchData,  
    html:true,  
    placement:'right'  
     });  
     function fetchData(){  
    var fetch_data = '';  
    var element = $(this);  
    var id = element.attr("id");  
    $.ajax({  
   url:"includes/modDashboard/GetSummaryInfo.php",  
   method:"POST",  
   async:false,  
   data:{id:id},  
   success:function(data){  
  fetch_data = data;  
   }  
    });  
    return fetch_data;  
     }  
});
```

Comment: Ok, but after success load the request you need to hide the popover. Right ?

Comment: nope popover remains open until mouse out i found a similar thing on this link http://jsfiddle.net/wormmd/sb7bx5e4/ but its really difficult to integrate but you will be clear for what I am looking for

Comment: Now i got it :) It is not so difficult Rtra.
Just need to parse the data from success callback.
for (var k in data) {
  $().append(data[k])
}

Comment: lolz i know but I am not too good in coding

Comment: For that purpose have been created stackoverflow :) 
can you create jsfiddle with your code ?
I will try to help you

Comment: @tailhour here you go on my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fzqhcjma/

Comment: So,
First you need to show loading text when request start.
The question is where ?
I did not see the loading spiner

And after that in  the same place need to parse the data

Comment: The popover triggers on hover function i want to show the spinner on popover before contents load

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fzqhcjma/1/

Something like this ...
Of course when data arrived you will need to change the loading text to smth else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144745/discussion-between-rtra-and-tailhour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution related to the issue:
[jshiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzqhcjma/20/)

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover1" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="cash_4">
        Cash Summary
    </a>
```

Good luck and regards Rtra :)